# postgresql odbc is not storing utf8 correctly into json/jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, odbc

I'm using odbc at my application(client side), trying to insert a list of  utf-8 encoded characters into postgresql json column. I'm using postgresOdbcUnicode driver V11.1.
At server side, the srvEncoding and clientEncoding are all set to UTF-8.
The odbc binding code in the application is :

```
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, ordinal, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, columnSize, 0/*decimalDigits*/, valuePtr, 0/*bufferLength*/, strLen_or_indPtr);
```

However, the actual content that is stored is scrambled : for example, `ö` is stored as `Ã¶`.
it looks like the driver or something in the postgres srv treats my input string as win1252, and convert them into UTF8, thus
`ö` becomes `Ã¶`.
My question is what i'm missing here..

Comment: What is the value of the `client_encoding` parameter in that database session?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe but how to set that from the odbc interface?

Comment: You can use the SQL statement `SET` to change a parameter for the current database session.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Tried this but not working. And it turns out i have to use sqlDriverConnect and define "ConnSettings=set client_encoding=UTF8;" in the input string to set the encoding for this connection

Comment: Only now I see the last comment. Could you please post this comment as your own answer and accept it? I can't, the cops are onto me now.